# can i use ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender in visual studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, modalpopupextender

I have a project in asp.net web form which is developed in visual studio 2005. I am trying to use modal popup(using  ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender) but it's not working.But it's perfectly works in vs2010. This make me confused. Is it possible to make it happen in vs2005.

Comment: I think the error is something like this: `Element "ModalPopupExtender" is not a known element`. The suitable AJAX Control Toolkit for VS 2005 & .NET 2.0 is 1.0.20229, make sure you're adding its reference in web.config: `<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>`.

Comment: thank you so much. i am working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you try to flow this code
--add ajaxcontroltoolkit---

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

-- take fale button---

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="" ID="lnkFake" runat="server" />
```

--- then you take this code---

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup"
                TargetControlID="lnkFake" CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Width="50%" Style="display: none;
                background-color: lightsteelblue;">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor="Green" ID="lblModelShow" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                <div style="display: block; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 700px; text-align: center"
                    class="textarea">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="Div1" style="overflow: scroll; height: 620px;">
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="1px" Width="750px" CellPadding="4"
                                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SL">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
                                <RowStyle CssClass="AlternatColor" Width="80px" ForeColor="#003399" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" CssClass="AlternatColor" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" BorderStyle="Double" Width="80px" Font-Bold="True"
                                    ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
```

--- this is c# code---
---  which event wise  you can try to show your propup ----

```
 mpe.Show();
```

Comment: Bare in mind that you need to use whatever you set into the TagPrefix of the assembly registration. For example here it's set as cc1, therefore in .aspx code it should be <cc1:ModalPopupExtender> instead of <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

Answer (score 0):

Also you Can use this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %> 



<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbutton" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="lnkbutton"
            CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup " align="center" Style="display: none">
            <h2 style="color: #000; text-decoration: underline">
                <asp:Label ID="lblGridHeader" runat="server" Text="`enter code here`Points Redeem"></asp:Label></h2>
                <div>

                </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>
```

Style:

```
<style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        .modalBackground {
            background-color: #ccc;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: .9;
        }

        .modalPopup {
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 900px !important;

        }

        @-webkit-keyframes blinker {
            from {
                opacity: 1.0;
            }

            to {
                opacity: 0.2;
            }
        }

        .blink {
            text-decoration: blink;
            -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
        }

        .modal {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #0000009e;
            z-index: 500;
            opacity: 1;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 100%;

        }

        .modal-backdrop {
            position: fixed;
            top: auto;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1040;
            background-color: #000;
        }

        .modal-dialog {
            width: 1220px;
        }
    </style>
```